# Difficulty in connecting oracle in different client

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle9i

I wrote a program with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 ,.NET Framework 3.5 SP1

To connect an Oracle database and fetch some data, this program works fine on my machine even if I use VS component or if I create connection and adapter by myself. This program also work fine in my friend PC that installed same version of visual studio but we have problem with the other client.
I already update them with latest .Net Framework but still they cannot connect.

I try to add my Oracle dll also same problem (I cannot remember, you can advice me again if you think problem is from this part). Even I copy that dll to their system32, windows directory but nothing happened.

I am wondering would you mind help me to solve the issue?

I wrote my program in C# and my Oracle database is 9i. FYI, I already try so many search regarding my problem but still I am not successful.

You can refer to my screen shot. thanks

[image]

Comment: As the error box clearly states: **..requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater** - so install that client software on that computer and you should be fine.

Comment: @marc_s: I think there should be easier solution. I found this website http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb00612.html  it is not free, any idea?

Comment: It looks like, your application uses some oracle client libraries. Do you have an oracle client installed on your development box? If yes - then try to mess with environment variables reuqired by oracle, so that it would break original oracle client functionality and run your application and watch, if it breaks too.

Comment: @ipip: For developing any oracle application in VS you need to add OracleClient.ddl that is available in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.OracleClient.dll. then all the component/packages will appear for you to use them.  in this case what should I do?

Comment: You're going to need to find a copy of the Oracle 9i client software and get it installed.  Putting a new version of OracleClient.dll on the target machine won't help - you need a newer version of the low-level Oracle software.  I was unable to locate the 9i client on Oracle's site as 9i is no longer supported, but if you hunt around you can probably find it somewhere.  Good luck.

Comment: The "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.OracleClient.dll" is dependent on some library provided by "Oracle client 8.1.7" product. Is there any useful information, when you click the "Details" button.
What is value of ORACLE_HOME environment variable?

Comment: @ipip:In my mechine ORACLE_HOME environment variable is empty!

Comment: @ipip: product version 2.0.50727.3082 this is the only useful thing I think

Comment: @bobjarvis: what do u mean by "you need a newer version of the low-level Oracle software." I didnt get u

Comment: I try to add oracleClient.dll for .netFramework 1.1 but some function wasnot available. Do you think if I install .NetFramework 2.0 my problem will solve?

Comment: You should install the oracle client (or database - it includes the client stuff) software, preferably the version, the library requires.

Comment: Go to [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html), download the appropriate client, and install it.  Or go to the page in the response from @RamiShareef (below), download the client, and install it.  This is the "client software" referred to in the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Oracle client software from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) then install it on your clients machines, everything must work fine for your clients